Two web app urls opened at same time, one web app url login is not working
I'm working on reactjs project there is login page open in two tabs at same time for different mills but when we try to login on first url then it's custom-referrer is updating with latest url and second one is showing blank page.
I have tried to use custom-referrer in localStorage to prevent custom-referrer url with latest url on form base login page.please guide me will this usefull if yes then how we can use in reactjs project.

When you work with local storage, even though you have two different tabs open, local storage remains the same for both.
If you want to see different behavior within two different tabs, You need to create a key that is unique and that you can easily read and write. For example, if you name the key simply URL, that URL is common to both website tabs. And if the value of any one tab changes, the B tab will also be auto-reflected.
You can use sessionStorage is you don't have need of maintaining details after user close the window. Session storage is isolated for different tabs. This means that one tab's session storage value is different from another's session value.
